# How to iterate through command output in eshell

Tags: emacs, eshell

I know I could use `xargs`, but I'm in eshell! There must be a slicker way of doing it. Let's say I run

```
find . -name "*.suo"
```

What's an eshell way of iterating through the results to `rm` each? I've tried `for` and `mapc` but not being very good at this stuff yet can't quite figure out how to use them for this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works from eshell, but maybe dired is more suitable for the job (?)

I would just open . in dired, then do something like search for '.suo' iterate to the result, mark files using m and then delete using x.